# What else should I replace when replacing valve cover gasket?

Tags: maintenance, toyota

Since I'm investing in time to replace valve cover gasket, should I have mechanic inspect/repair/replace anything else related to valve cover assembly/dis-assembly?

Vehicle is 1997 Toyota Sienna.

Comment: I got the 2 valve cover gaskets, Thermostat (water outlet), spark plugs + wires, pcv valve done for $280 labor @ Houston.

Comment: Welcome to the site @Ganesh! Perhaps if you included the price of just the valve cover gasket (parts + specific labor from receipt), then this anecdote could help OP figure out how cost effective doing the thermostat, plugs, wires, and pcv valve at the same time is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were recommended a valve cover gasket because it was leaking, just make sure that the fastener seals are also replaced. If not, they are guaranteed to go next. As far as any other components go, if they are attached to the valve cover in any way, you should likely consider replacing those seals as well.

Answer (score 4):

One component I like to do with valve cover gaskets, since it only involves a few more bolts, are the cam seals (if you have overhead cams). You'll have the valve cover off, so you should be doing this anyway, but be sure that you don't allow any debris to fall in there, especially on the cam journals. This could lead to a catastrophic failure in your vehicle requiring expensive repairs.

Comment: Sorry for reviving an old thread! I'm just reading up about gasket covers (total noob) as I have to have mine replaced on a 2009 Hyundai H1 van (also called iMax/Starex). I've got the 2.4l petrol and the gasket is leaking oil.
What else would be beneficial to have the mechanic done while he's in there? The car has a shoddy service history but now that she belongs to me, I'd like to keep her running smoothly for many more kilo's.